# jQuery - returned value using json skips the first object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following piece of code:

```
var url = "/MyURL";
$.get(url, function (dataUrl) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "MyURL?PrjID="+ prjid +" ",
        data: dataUrl,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true
    }).success(function (data, textStatus) {
        console.log(data)
       })
});
```

Following is the result retrieved from the webservice (MyURL) which is a valid JSON string

```
[{"ProteinID":"O15247","GeneName":"CLIC2"}, 
{"ProteinID":"O95833","GeneName":"CLIC3"}, 
{"ProteinID":"Q9Y696","GeneName":"CLIC4"}, 
{"ProteinID":"O15516","GeneName":"CLOCK"}]
```

But, the actual `objects` that are retrieved from the JSON request have always one less element than the actual data and more precisely the first record of the result-set is always skipped. For the above example the result I get (the log from the console) is the following:

```
0: Object { ProteinID: "O95833", GeneName: "CLIC3" }
1: Object { ProteinID: "Q9Y696", GeneName: "CLIC4" }
2: Object { ProteinID: "O15516", GeneName: "CLOCK" }
```

Any idea what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `console.log(data)` is giving you the wrong result, but the response from the server (network tab) is correct?

Comment: Not sure it matters but you forgot a closing parenthesis "`)`". 

`.success(function (data, textStatus) { console.log(data) })`

Comment: @Andy exactly, the returned result from the server is a JSON object with 4 elements while the console.log(data) upon a successful request returns 3 elements.

Comment: @gkoul Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`. Maybe you later on change this object and console prints does not happens immediately when called.

Comment: exactly the same result `[{"ProteinID":"O95833","GeneName":"CLIC3"},{"ProteinID":"Q9Y696","GeneName":"CLIC4"},{"ProteinID":"O15516","GeneName":"CLOCK"}]` as a string this time

Comment: try to remove `async: true`, Cross-domain requests do not support synchronous operation.

Comment: @WaelAbbas I removed it and nothing changed. I also changed the `crossDomain: true` from `true` to `false` either with or without the `async: true`

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying that you want to display the first element, just to see what is at [0] ?

Comment: @SPlatten just did it and got this `{"ProteinID":"O95833","GeneName":"CLIC3"}​` , which is the second record of the expected data.

Comment: Try doing the following on your data that you are submitting, before you submit it, console.dir(data);  I suspect the submitted data isn't as you think.

Comment: @SPlatten that was my issue, the problem was finally occurring before the JSON request. I fixed that and everything seems to work fine now.